cmake: how to specify generator path in command-line and presets?
CMake ignores PATH and only looks in /usr/bin.
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:2 (project):
  Running
   '/usr/bin/ninja' '--version'
  failed with:
   no such file or directory

How to correct this behavior and let cmake use generator from specific path in command-line and presets.json?

You probably ask about CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM variable. You could specify it in the command line with -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=<...> option.

"CMake ignores PATH and only looks in /usr/bin." - This is not true. CMake definitely uses PATH when searches for ninja executable. Probably, you have firstly configured your project when the path /usr/bin/ninja was valid, and forgot to clear the cache after that.
